# Item returned from a tkinter combobox is <class 'str'> rather than str itself

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Can someone please clearly explain what the difference is? Result of a callback function is  when I try to return the value. However, I need to return the value itself which the type must be str or int.
I can see the value taken from dropdown menu, but I am not able to really use it in my other calculations.

```
od=[1927,1929,1930,1931]

comboExample = ttk.Combobox(subframe,textvariable=tk.IntVar(), values=od, state='normal')

comboExample.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=10)

comboExample.current(0)

def callbackFunc_od(event):
    OD=comboExample.get()
    print(OD)
    return OD

comboExample.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackFunc_od)
```

Comment: How do you know what the value returned from the combobox is anything other than the string? When I run your code, `print(OD)` prints the actual string value. The return value is irrelevant since nothing will receive the value returned from callbacks.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. I use print(type(OD) and get <class 'str'> rather than str itself. However, if I want to use this callback function in somewhere else like in a loop, how should I use it?  What argument should be placed in parenthesis callbackFunc_od(?)

Comment: Yes, `print(type(OD))` will print `<class 'str'>`. That's telling you that the value returned from the `.get()` method is a string.

Comment: Thanks. So, my question is that how I can get VALUE e.g. 1927 having selected it, and use it for my other purposes for example to retrieve something else or use this value (1927) in another loop. I would really appreciate if you can help me. I mean how I can use that callback function to get 1927?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `.get()` call on a widget will always be a string. Since you are wanting it to be integers, you need to associate an `IntVar` with the combobox, *save the reference to the `IntVar`*, and then get the value from the `IntVar`.

For example:

```
od_var = tk.IntVar()
comboExample = ttk.Combobox(...,textvariable=od_var, ...)
...
def callbackFunc_od(event):
    OD=od_var.get()
```

Comment: Many thanks. Now, how I can use this number? def API():                                              ...
def API()
        if callbackFunc_od in df['OD']:

Comment: @DataKurd: It's hard to understand what you're really asking. You use it like any other variable. It sounds like you actually want to use it in some other function, in which case you don't need `callbackFunc_od` at all. Whereever you need the value, just use `od_var.get()`.

Comment: O my goodness. You are right, I thought for updating my selection I need to have a callback function. Now I tested it and realized that thre is no need and as you said, I can just use od_var.get(). GOD BLESS YOU!